# What is the significance of using specifically a chicken for the Zero'ah?

Tags: minhag, passover, passover-seder-hagada, korban-pesach

The Chabad custom and possibly others is to use a chicken neck as the zero'ah.

Why specifically do we use a chicken to substitute for the Korban Pesach and not any other animal or fowl?

Comment: It is far away from being mistaken for a real Korban Pesach.

Comment: It was cheap and available in Eastern Europe (Id guess the significance of that is yearning for the days of old in Eastern Europe when chicken necks were all we could afford. השיבנו ונשוב!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Chabad.org** has an article titled "[The Shank Bone (Zeroah)](https://www.chabad.org/holidays/passover/pesach_cdo/aid/1999/jewish/The-Shank-Bone-Zeroah.htm#footnoteRef10a1999)" that addresses this custom: (also referenced in the comments by @[Yishai](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/440/yishai))

> **Since the zeroa symbolizes the Paschal sacrifice**, which was roasted, the custom is that the zeroa is roasted as well. However, since it is absolutely forbidden to sacrifice outside of the Temple Mount, and **we do not want it to appear as if we are (heaven forbid) eating an actual Paschal sacrifice**, we do not eat the zeroa. **This is also the reason some prefer to use limb of a bird** (***which does not at all resemble the Passover offering, which was a lamb or a kid)***, and then strip much of the flesh from the bone (see: Rebbe’s Haggadah). If you follow this custom, take care that some of the flesh should remain or it is not considered a zeroa (see: Shulchan Aruch Harav 673:22, quoting the Ran).

Following this line of reasoning, this would seem to rule out using other animals for the *zeroa* since it could be mistaken for the Paschal sacrifice.

In terms of why a chicken, I think @[DoubleAA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa)'s comment is correct: **there's no kosher bird for consumption that was and is more prevalent/ accessible than a chicken.**

- (side point: any Kosher meat restaurant is **almost guaranteed** to have a chicken option on the menu, but would not necessarily have: duck, quail, turkey, goose, pheasant etc or any of the other kosher birds)

Thus, while one could potentially suggest to use one of the aforementioned birds as their *zeroa* (obviously not before [CYLOR](https://www.yourdictionary.com/cylor)) it's understandable how the widespread practice of using a chicken bone for *zeroa* was adopted.

Comment: Is there any source for the notion that some prefer to use the limb of a bird?

Comment: To be clear I was commenting on why chicken instead of lamb, not chicken instead of duck.

Comment: This is not accurate. Pigeons are way more common than chickens, at least where I live.

Comment: @DoubleAA same for me (NYC) but nobody eats them, I'd assume the same by you

Comment: @alicht probably the same number of people eat the zeroa as eat pigeons

Comment: @DoubleAA added in "for consumption"